# How to start a app and have it start a WebDAV server automatically in Windows?

Tags: adb

I need to have some questions answered please. I want to start an app called WebDAV and have it start the server automatically. Do I find out the com.example.MyApp in the Settings/Apps section so I can reference it correctly? I also need to know what the adb command that I need to use and the correct syntax to use. I think it should be something along the lines of "adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW" but once the app is started how to make it start the WebDAV server. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal way. It all depends upon how the app is designed. For example, the app Servers Ultimate Pro (I use it) offers the option to start a server automatically  during app startup. While I'm unable to recall the name, I remember coming across an app which allowed toggling the status of a server through intent.

Your concerned app may or may not be designed to start the server once a particular Activity is launched. Simplest way is to understand the functioning of the app and reach the conclusion. Seeking assistance from app's developer *vis-à-vis* concerned feature may also help.

As for starting an app, use the package name with *am*.

```
adb shell am start <pkg>  # <pkg> refers to package name of the app to be launched. Its Main activity would be launched
```

If you want the app to launch into a particular Activity, do

```
adb shell am start -n <comp>  # <comp> refers to app's activity (a component) to be launched into. E.g. com.example.app/com.example.app.NewServerActivity
```